# how to move current record to another table and delete the current record

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently using PHP to create a system locally for user to insert data into 14 tables located in one page, then end of day all the data in that table should be move into a new table in database automatically named dashboard (will store daily data) but recently I used a button by click manually to take the action and at the same time all the data in 14 tables state above will be delete automatically. It easy to make user insert new data at the next day because today's data has been moved to another table also current table's data was empty. I have searching at all website about this matter but don't get any solution. Hope all you guys can help me out of this problem.

I used **INSERT INTO** but not working. Where should I used the **FROM** tag? Because there is 8 table need to transfer, eg: sr1, sr2, sr3 and so on.

My Code as below:

```
    if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")) {
  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO sr1_full (date, total_pending, appt_today, percent_appt_today, percent_complete, partial_complete, full_complete, return_technical, return_customer, return_cancel, cancel, reappt, focus, total_tepi, total_bawah) SELECT date, total_pending, appt_today, percent_appt_today, percent_complete, partial_complete, full_complete, return_technical, return_customer, return_cancel, cancel, reappt, focus, total_tepi, total_bawah FROM sr1 TRUNCATE TABLE sr1",
                           GetSQLValueString($_POST['date'], "date"),
                           GetSQLValueString($_POST['total_pending'], "int"),
                           GetSQLValueString($_POST['appt_today'], "int"),
                           GetSQLValueString($_POST['percent_appt_today'], "int"),
                           GetSQLValueString($_POST['percent_complete'], "int"),
                           GetSQLValueString($_POST['partial_complete'], "int"),
                           GetSQLValueString($_POST['full_complete'], "int"),
                           GetSQLValueString($_POST['return_technical'], "int"),
                           GetSQLValueString($_POST['return_customer'], "int"),
                           GetSQLValueString($_POST['return_cancel'], "int"),
                           GetSQLValueString($_POST['cancel'], "int"),
                           GetSQLValueString($_POST['reappt'], "int"),
                           GetSQLValueString($_POST['focus'], "int"),
                           GetSQLValueString($_POST['total_tepi'], "int"),
                           GetSQLValueString($_POST['total_bawah'], "int"));

      mysql_select_db($database_pods, $pods);
      $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $pods) or die(mysql_error());

      $insertGoTo = "main.php";
      if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
        $insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
        $insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
      }
      header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
    }

    mysql_select_db($database_pods, $pods);
    $query_sr1 = "SELECT * FROM sr1";
    $sr1 = mysql_query($query_sr1, $pods) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_sr1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sr1);
    $totalRows_sr1 = mysql_num_rows($sr1);

    mysql_select_db($database_pods, $pods);
    $query_sr2 = "SELECT * FROM sr2";
    $sr2 = mysql_query($query_sr2, $pods) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_sr2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sr2);
    $totalRows_sr2 = mysql_num_rows($sr2);

    mysql_select_db($database_pods, $pods);
    $query_sr3 = "SELECT * FROM sr3";
    $sr3 = mysql_query($query_sr3, $pods) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_sr3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sr3);
    $totalRows_sr3 = mysql_num_rows($sr3);

    mysql_select_db($database_pods, $pods);
    $query_sr4 = "SELECT * FROM sr4";
    $sr4 = mysql_query($query_sr4, $pods) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_sr4 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sr4);
    $totalRows_sr4 = mysql_num_rows($sr4);

    mysql_select_db($database_pods, $pods);
    $query_sr5 = "SELECT * FROM sr5";
    $sr5 = mysql_query($query_sr5, $pods) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_sr5 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sr5);
    $totalRows_sr5 = mysql_num_rows($sr5);

    mysql_select_db($database_pods, $pods);
    $query_stx = "SELECT * FROM stx";
    $stx = mysql_query($query_stx, $pods) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_stx = mysql_fetch_assoc($stx);
    $totalRows_stx = mysql_num_rows($stx);

    mysql_select_db($database_pods, $pods);
    $query_kl = "SELECT * FROM kl";
    $kl = mysql_query($query_kl, $pods) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_kl = mysql_fetch_assoc($kl);
    $totalRows_kl = mysql_num_rows($kl);

    mysql_select_db($database_pods, $pods);
    $query_msc = "SELECT * FROM msc";
    $msc = mysql_query($query_msc, $pods) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_msc = mysql_fetch_assoc($msc);
    $totalRows_msc = mysql_num_rows($msc);

    mysql_select_db($database_pods, $pods);
    $query_total = "SELECT * FROM total_bawah";
    $total = mysql_query($query_total, $pods) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_total = mysql_fetch_assoc($total);
    $totalRows_total = mysql_num_rows($total);
```

Comment: This seems overly complicated. Just store everything in `all_dashboard` with a date/timestamp, and for "Today" only select records with the date from the date from the date/timestamp matching today's date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this SQL to copy data.

```
insert into `CopyTable` (`colum1`,`colum2`) select `colum1`,`colum2` from `Sourcetable`
```

empty table by

```
TRUNCATE TABLE  `Sourcetable`
```

example :

```
$insertSQL = "INSERT INTO sr1_full (`date`, `total_pending`, `appt_today`, `percent_appt_today`, `percent_complete`, `partial_complete`, `full_complete`, `return_technical`, `return_customer`, `return_cancel`, `cancel`, `reappt`, `focus`, `total_tepi`, `total_bawah`) SELECT `date`, `total_pending`, `appt_today`, `percent_appt_today`, `percent_complete`, `partial_complete`, `full_complete`, `return_technical`, `return_customer`, `return_cancel`, `cancel`, `reappt`, `focus`, `total_tepi`, `total_bawah` FROM `sr1`";

mysql_query($insertSQL); // data copied.

$removeSQL = "TRUNCATE TABLE sr1";

mysql_query($removeSQL); // deleted all data from sr1

//data moved
```

Comment: @mastersuse, 

**insert into `Backuptable` (`colum1`,`colum2`,...) select `colum1`,`colum2` from `sr1`

TRUNCATE TABLE  `sr1`

insert into `Backuptable` (`colum1`,`colum2`,...) select `colum1`,`colum2` from `sr2`

TRUNCATE TABLE  `sr2`**

similarly you can move data from all the other tables to backup table. if you have any further queries, ask me... :)

Comment: may I know, between `insert into Backuptable (colum1,colum2,...) select colum1,colum2 from sr1 TRUNCATE TABLE sr1` and `insert into Backuptable (colum1,colum2,...) select colum1,colum2 from sr2 TRUNCATE TABLE sr2` It's just continue writing (just like your example above) or there is a special symbol to seperate them?

Comment: hello, I just edit my code again, look above and correct for me, I used INSERT INTO SELECT FROM TRUNCATE TABLE syntax, It that all correct? because I got an error `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TABLE sr1' at line 1`

Comment: @mastersuse, TRUNCATE TABLE `table name` is separate SQL statement

Comment: @mastersuse, I've added an example by editing my answer. Pls check it.

Comment: you are really great! very helpful, your code are working for me! thanks so much buddy!

Comment: I just want to confirm, as you know I have 8 table want to do same as above (copy data, transfer it and truncated), so is that I must repeat as you have edited code above for another table?

Comment: if you don't understand my explanation please let me know. :)

Comment: @mastersuse, Yes, you have to repeat this for all the 8 tables... check column names..

Comment: I just want to know, can I combine the code as below by using comma symbol or any symbol? OR must do it separately. by default as above `$removeSQL = "TRUNCATE TABLE sr1";` after merge it be like this `$removeSQL = "TRUNCATE TABLE sr1, sr2, sr3";` can I used like this?

Comment: hi, can you help me at [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12314346/how-to-merge-table-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're having a hard time finding information on how to do this is that this is *not* the correct way to do this.

You should not be duplicating the structure of a table to store data for "today" and data for previous days. What you *should* do is store all items in a single dashboard table, and filter based on a date column to determine which items are considered today's items. The approach you're trying to take, of moving rows from a current table to an archive table, is flat-out *wrong*. That isn't how databases work.

All that said, you would accomplish this by using [`select into table`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html) to move all the data from `today_dashboard` into `all_dashboard`, and then `delete from today_dashboard` to clear it out. **Don't do this**. Rethink your architecture to store both in one table.

Comment: I really like your explanation, really understand, I'll try it then I'll reply back.

Answer (score 1):

```
$current_date = date("m.d.y"); 
$query = "INSERT INTO table_name (date,column1, column2, column3,...)
          VALUES ($current_date,value1, value2, value3,...)";
$result=mysql_query($query);
```

- This way you have to insert all the dats to your tabel with the current date.
- After saving records to database you have to check the current date was matched to any records. IF any records found you have to delete this record by using delete query. This way you can delete all existing  records from that table

  Hope this will be useful for you...