# How to merge table in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I just want to merge/combine this tables into one query, but it not working. Actually there is too many tables and column but for this example I just put certain only.

```
$insertSQL_sr1 = "INSERT INTO sr1_full (`date`, `total_pending`, `appt_today`, `percent_appt_today`) SELECT `date`, `total_pending`, `appt_today`, `percent_appt_today` FROM `sr1`";

$insertSQL_sr2 = "INSERT INTO sr2_full (`date`, `total_pending`, `appt_today`, `percent_appt_today`) SELECT `date`, `total_pending`, `appt_today`, `percent_appt_today` FROM `sr2`";

$insertSQL_sr3 = "INSERT INTO sr3_full (`date`, `total_pending`, `appt_today`, `percent_appt_today`) SELECT `date`, `total_pending`, `appt_today`, `percent_appt_today` FROM `sr3`";

$insertSQL_full = $insertSQL_sr1.";".$insertSQL_sr2.";".$insertSQL_sr3;

mysql_query($insertSQL_full);

mysql_select_db($database_pods, $pods);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL_full, $pods) or die(mysql_error());
```

An Error Appear:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO sr2_full (`date`, `total_pending`, `appt_today`, `percent_appt_today' at line 1
```

My Second Edit:

```
$insertSQL = "INSERT INTO sr1_full (`date`, `total_pending`, `appt_today`, `percent_appt_today`) SELECT `date`, `total_pending`, `appt_today`, `percent_appt_today` FROM `sr1`; INSERT INTO sr2_full (`date`, `total_pending`, `appt_today`, `percent_appt_today`) SELECT `date`, `total_pending`, `appt_today`, `percent_appt_today` FROM `sr2`; INSERT INTO sr3_full (`date`, `total_pending`, `appt_today`, `percent_appt_today`) SELECT `date`, `total_pending`, `appt_today`, `percent_appt_today` FROM `sr3`";

mysql_select_db($database_pods, $pods);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $pods) or die(mysql_error());
```

An Error Appear:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO sr2_full (`date`, `total_pending`, `appt_today`, `percent_appt_today' at line 1
```

Comment: I am not able to understand your problem - are you getting any error message?

Comment: Do you want to UNION your rows or to JOIN them?

Comment: Can't understand what do you want or what your problem is.

Comment: sorry for my bad English, I has edited my code above.

Comment: for your reference you can visit [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12215356/how-to-move-current-record-to-another-table-and-delete-the-current-record)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$insertSQL1 = "INSERT INTO sr1_full (`date`, `total_pending`, `appt_today`, `percent_appt_today`) SELECT `date`, `total_pending`, `appt_today`, `percent_appt_today` FROM `sr1`";

$insertSQL2 = "INSERT INTO sr2_full (`date`, `total_pending`, `appt_today`, `percent_appt_today`) SELECT `date`, `total_pending`, `appt_today`, `percent_appt_today` FROM `sr2`";

$insertSQL3 = "INSERT INTO sr3_full (`date`, `total_pending`, `appt_today`, `percent_appt_today`) SELECT `date`, `total_pending`, `appt_today`, `percent_appt_today` FROM `sr3`";
```

Add `;` to combine two SQL statements.

You can combine these queries like this.

```
$insertSQL_Single = $insertSQL1.";".$insertSQL2.";".$insertSQL3;
```

resulting query :

```
INSERT INTO sr1_full (`date`, `total_pending`, `appt_today`, `percent_appt_today`) SELECT `date`, `total_pending`, `appt_today`, `percent_appt_today` FROM `sr1`;INSERT INTO sr2_full (`date`, `total_pending`, `appt_today`, `percent_appt_today`) SELECT `date`, `total_pending`, `appt_today`, `percent_appt_today` FROM `sr2`;INSERT INTO sr3_full (`date`, `total_pending`, `appt_today`, `percent_appt_today`) SELECT `date`, `total_pending`, `appt_today`, `percent_appt_today` FROM `sr3`
```

I've tried this using PhpMyAdmin. query was success

it can't be executed by **mysql_query()**. lets find some other tricks. we need to execute it separate.

Use mysqli for executing this

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("host","username","password", "databasename");
if (!$mysqli->multi_query($insertSQL_Single)) {
    echo "Multi query failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}
else
{
    echo "success";
}
```

Comment: I has do what you said, the code as above but have an error appear.

Comment: @mastersuse, i've edited my answer also. please check the resulting query.

Comment: @mastersuse, it can't be executed by mysql_query. lets find some other tricks. we need to execute it separate.

Comment: I have edit my 2nd edit just now still got the error. please let me out of this problem.. :'( can you help me?

Comment: it can't be executed by mysql_query(). lets find some other tricks. we need to execute it separate.

Comment: but actually I found in a website that query can be used, but why my query cannot? look [here](http://forums.macrumors.com/archive/index.php/t-990852.html)

Comment: @mastersuse, ys we can use like this

`$SQLarray = explode(';',$insertSQL_Single);

foreach($SQLarray as $SQL)
{
mysql_query($SQL);
}`

but its similar as we execute 3 queries seperate

Comment: @mastersuse, Please check my answer. using mysqli, it got success

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16433/discussion-between-mastersuse-and-mansoorkhan-cherupuzha)

Comment: I give you green tick for your help, It's very helpful.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I think he wants to copy data from one table to another. Just read it out in one step, store it temporary in some PHP variable and then insert it in another step.

Comment: for your reference, you can visit [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12215356/how-to-move-current-record-to-another-table-and-delete-the-current-record)

Comment: I just want to combine all the query into one query, can we do that?